# Como importar arquivos de fontes do bootstrap

Tags: php, css, bootstrap

Os ícones do bootstrap não estão pegando em meu projeto. Pesquisei e vi que pode ser resolvido importando os arquivos de fonte do bootstrap. Qual a melhor forma de importar esses arquivos no body de uma página?

Comment: Jovem, posta o seu código ai inclusive com a `<head>`. Pode ser que o seu problema seja com a indexação dos arquivos etc. Pois com a resposta que dei abaixo deveria funcionar por ai também...

Answer (score 2):

Você pode importar direto no `<head>` do seu site dessa forma por exemplo

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">
```

Ou se quiser pode chamar pelo `<style>` ou direto no .CSS dessa forma por exemplo:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
      src: url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
      src: url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
           url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
    }
</style>
```

E onde quiser usar os ícones lembre de colocar `font-family`

Aqui tem o projeto do Glyphicon no GitHub https://github.com/ohpyupi/glyphicons-only-bootstrap

**Exemplo de aplicação por CDN:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">

<p>Envelope: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></p>
```

**Exemplo de aplicação pelo `@font-face` no `<style>` ou `.css`:**

```css
@font-face {
      font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
      src: url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
      src: url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
           url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal 16px/1 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
/* Código do ícone */
.glyphicon-fire:before {
  content: '\e104';
}
```

```html
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"> fogo na bomba</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Porém os icons ainda não estão funcionando, sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Edite sua resposta com o código completo que vai ficar mais fácil para te responder de forma mais precisa. Mas com o código acima deveria funcionar...

Comment: Também acho que deveria, estou usando semantic ui também, será que isso pode ocasionar erro?

Comment: Nesse caso só pesquisando para saber... Se vc puder testar em outro ambiente já seria bom pra matar a dúvida.

Comment: Em meu caso, quando realizei o donwload do Bootstrap 4 ele não vem com a pasta fonts. E apesar de não vim com essa pasta, dentro da pasta css não possui o arquivo glyphicon ou derivados dele.

Comment: @FelipeRoque é isso mesmo, o  BS4 não vem com Ícones nativamente, te sugiro usar o FontAwesome ou o Material Icons, ou então faz como nesse último exemplo da minha pergunta e usa o Glyphicon no BS4

Comment: @hugocsl eu linkei essas duas tags e funcionou :
 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">`